# How to cache url and content with apache2 and proxy/reverse-proxy?

Tags: apache2.4

I have enable the cache and cache_disk module in my apache2 2.4.6 version.

I am unable to cache my url and its content to a directory, my apache configuration code is:

```
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName mysite.local
    ServerAlias *
     ProxyRequests off
     <Proxy *>
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
    ProxyPreserveHost on
    LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so
    <IfModule mod_cache.c>
      LoadModule cache_disk_module modules/mod_cache_disk.so
      <IfModule mod_cache_disk.c>
        CacheRoot /var/www/mysiteCache/
        CacheEnable disk  /
        CacheDirLevels 5
        CacheDirLength 3
     </IfModule>
     # When acting as a proxy, don't cache the list of security updates
    CacheDisable http://security.update.server/update-list/
 </IfModule>
```

Please give me idea how to cache my url data?

Thanks,
Vijay